# PostgreSQL doesn't remove duplicates

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to remove some duplicates from my DB.
It's a table with location data for a map.Some points have been entered twice and i am trying to remove them.

This is the code that i have used

```
delete from test_table a 
using test_table b 
where a.location_x = b.location_x and a.location_y = b.location_y and a.type = b.type and a.ctid < b.ctid;
```

and it has removed some duplicates.However i can see on the map that there are still some duplicates.
Searching them by their id shows me indeed that they have the same location x and y,however they do not get deleted by the script.

this is a point in the map that shows up twice
[image]

Any ideas on why it's not working?
Thank you

Comment: The trick for using ctid is useful if there's truly no visible difference between the rows, but you have a primary key, so you could just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *sure* they're equal? Those are double precision floating point numbers, and [they are not precise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems). Try checking their equality.

To avoid these sorts of problems, use [arbitrary precision numbers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) or [Postgres's point type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html).

Comment: Thanks,i was able to solve it by converting them to numeric type and running it again

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why its not working, however, I would do it this way:

1)

```
  select a.ctid
  from test_table a 
  where exists
  (select 1 test_table b 
  where a.location_x = b.location_x and a.location_y = b.location_y and a.type = b.type and 
  a.ctid < b.ctid
)
```

gives the ids that will be deleted

and the code below deletes them

2)

```
delete from test_table where ctid in
(
  select a.ctid
  from test_table a 
  where exists
  (select 1 test_table b 
  where a.location_x = b.location_x and a.location_y = b.location_y and a.type = b.type and 
  a.ctid < b.ctid
  )
)
```

Comment: I tried your way with @kmkaplan 's advice but it was taking a really long time to compute,i left it on for 1.5 hours so i shut it down.

Answer (score 0):

Your location coordinates are floating point numbers. They probably differ in decimal places that are not displayed by your data browser. They are not suited to be compared for equality. The usual practice is to test if they are "close enough".

Try replacing `a.location_x = b.location_x and a.location_y = b.location_y` by `abs(a.location_x - b.location_x) < 0.0000001 and abs(a.location_y - b.location_y) < 0.0000001`